# Registration Code and Recaptcha

Tags: php, registration, recaptcha

I apologize beforehand for the lack of structure in this code. I know it's not efficient or pretty, hell, with my addition of recaptcha it is not even functional right now. Which brings me to my question, what is wrong with the code? Why doesn't the captcha appear? How can I make it better?

```
<?php
include('config.php');
#reCaptcha
require_once('recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "dsafsdfasdfq2Fv9JfDUBnOCTpm7S";
$privatekey = "asdfasdfasdfaMR15mi7sXXnv42-fffffffff";
$resp = null;
$error = null;
#Setup Credentials
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$escapedPW = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
#Salt Credentials
$salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
$saltedPW =  $escapedPW . $salt;
$hashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW);
#checks and query
$usercheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$uname'");
$emailcheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($usercheck);
$count2 = mysql_num_rows($emailcheck);
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, salt) VALUES ('$uname', '$hashedPW', '$email', '$salt')";
$result = "";
#recaptcha validation
                 function register(){
    if(empty($_POST['uname']) || empty($_POST['pass']) || empty($_POST['email'] )){
      echo 'A field is empty!';}      
    else{
            if($count != 0){$result = 'Username is already registered.';}
            elseif ($count2 != 0 ) {$result = 'Email is already registered.';}
                else{ mysql_query($query); $result = 'Registration Successful!';}
      }
  }

if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]) {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
        if ($resp->is_valid) {
          register();
        } else {
              die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
        }
} 
?>
<html><head><title>Register</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" /></head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">      
         <div id="container">
    <?php echo $result; ?>
<div class="center">
        <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" onclick="this.value=''" value="Username"  name="uname" /> <br />
        <input type="password" onclick="this.value=''" value="password" name="pass" /> <br />
        <input type="email" onclick="this.value=''" value="Email" name="email" /> <br />
        <?php recaptcha_get_html($publickey); ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"></form>
        <html><head></head></div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes vaahost is correct you can try that source.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the below code after `<input type="email" onclick="this.value=''" value="Email" name="email" /> <br />`

## Add This

```
# the response from reCAPTCHA
$resp = null;
# the error code from reCAPTCHA, if any
$error = null;

# was there a reCAPTCHA response?
if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]) {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        if ($resp->is_valid) {
                echo "You got it!";
        } else {
                # set the error code so that we can display it
                $error = $resp->error;
        }
}
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
```